# Putting a Report Title on every page

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have HTML view using 2010 .NET, which I am generating in the report format, so that users could view it and print it. However, when the report turns out to be more than one page, obviously the Report Title does not appear on pages 2,3, and so on.
I heard that there is something that could be done using CSS to force the title to appear on every page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [print CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/). It is a specific CSS which is applied when printing. So you could hide the title in your main CSS and show it in your print CSS.